# Passing value from Android to ASP.net

Tags: android, asp.net, http-post

How do I pass a value from Android to Asp.net web application using http post method?

Comment: What did you try? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: I haven't really tried anything cause I don't have the basic knowledge of http programming so I was wondering if anyone could teach me by posting some examples?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=android+http+examples